# mysql error data grouping sum in sub query. it is showing same sum on all dates

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT collectionta.MonthYearAutoGen,
   (SELECT sum(Collection) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'HDFC 875 KM') as 'HDFC 875 KM',
   (SELECT Sum(Collection) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'synd 233 SET') as 'synd 233 SET',
   (SELECT Sum(Collection) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'Synd 217 KM') as 'Synd 217 KM'
 FROM accounts.collectionta
 GROUP BY collectionta.MonthYearAutoGen order by collectionta.DateInput;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztMDm.png)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please format your code (sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date_format(DateInput, '%M %Y') As Month_Years, (SELECT sum(case when Date_format(DateInput, '%M %Y') = Month_Years  Then Collection else 0 end) from accounts.collectionta  where collectionta.modeId = 'HDFC 875 KM') as 'HDFC 875 KM', (SELECT sum(case when Date_format(DateInput, '%M %Y') = Month_Years  Then Collection else 0 end) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'synd 233 SET') as 'synd 233 SET', (SELECT sum(case when Date_format(DateInput, '%M %Y') = Month_Years  Then Collection else 0 end) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'Synd 217 KM') as 'Synd 217 KM', (SELECT sum(case when Date_format(DateInput, '%M %Y') = Month_Years  Then Collection else 0 end) from accounts.collectionta where collectionta.modeId = 'Cash') as 'Cash' FROM accounts.collectionta GROUP BY Month_Years order by collectionta.DateInput desc limit 12;
```